# Delete time minutes from time object python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a field in a pandas dataframe which I want to truncate the minute from, i.e cast from time to string, split it and retain the hour only.

The time field in my dataframe is of type object and what I have tried to do is as below (accidents is my pandas dataframe by the way):

```
for row in range (1, len(accidents)):

    hour = row['Time'].strftime("%H").split(":", 1)[0]
```

For example, what I want to do is to change 17:45 to 17.

Image of accidents Dataframe is as below.

[image]

The datatype for the Time object is as below.

[image]

When I run the above code, I get an error "TypeError : 'int' object is not subscriptable"

I know this is a casting error of some form, but I don't know how to fix it.
(I am pretty new to Python).

The csv file can be re-produced (truncated here to include the relevant field only) if requested.
Accident_Index,Location_Easting_OSGR,Location_Northing_OSGR,Longitude,Latitude,Police_Force,Accident_Severity,Number_of_Vehicles,Number_of_Casualties,Date,Day_of_Week,Time,
200501BS00001,525680,178240,-0.191170,51.489096,1,2,1,1,04/01/2005,3,17:42

Comment: Please include sample input

Comment: Updated. I don't know if I can add a dataframe to run here.

Comment: @user6074035 umm... are you after: `df['Time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)` ?

Comment: Hi Jon, you have fixed it for me!! If you add it as a proper answer, I will mark it as the solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module's `strftime()` needs to have a format argument (see proper usage below).

```
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
'08/09/2020, 02:48:25'
```

(A good `strftime()` cheat-sheet is available [here](https://strftime.org/))

In your case, it looks like you're just trying to get the hour number. For this, you should use the following format string to just get the hour: `"%H"`. If you need to get this as an integer (if you need to do math with it), you can simply surround it by `int()`. If you're just going to display this number, you can leave it as a string. `strftime()` returns a string by default.

Try this code:

```
hour = int(row['Time'].strftime("%H"))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I tried that but I still get the same error (I had forgotten about the parameter in the strftime but I still get the same error.

Comment: @user6074035 Hm, that's odd. Can you edit your post to include the full text of the traceback?

Comment: Hey, I will try to figure out how to do that, I need to figure out how to add the full stack trace in Spyder as it doesn't give it by default. I have added the datatypes of the dataframe in case that helps. I will have a look for the full stack trace now. (I added the "%H" to my original question as well - thanks!)

Comment: If you add "print(type(row['Time']))" to your program above your "hour = ..." statement, does it print "<class 'datetime.datetime'>"? If not, what does it print? I don't know the rest of the program, but I do know that some database accessing libraries will automatically convert date column results to datetime.datetime objects, however I want to make sure that's the case.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help here. I actually get the same error "TypeError....."

Comment: I have added a sample of the CSV to the original question in case it helps. I read this in to a pandas dataframe

Comment: Jon Clements has answered the question for me. Thanks for your help and input Josh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hour` attribute of the *Time* column

```
d = [d for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,5,1,2), 
                          dt.datetime(2020,5,3,4), freq="45min") 
     ] # miss some sample times... 

# random manipulation of rawIdx so there are some rows where ts is not in rawIdx
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time":d, 
                   "val":[random.randint(0,50) for x in d]})

df["Hour"] = df["Time"].dt.hour
print(df.head().to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
               Time  val  Hour
2020-05-01 02:00:00   39     2
2020-05-01 02:45:00   23     2
2020-05-01 03:30:00    9     3
2020-05-01 04:15:00   25     4
2020-05-01 05:00:00   41     5
```